# vertical-align:middle changes containing div's position

Tags: css

I'm using bootstrap, which contains the rule

```
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For the following css and markup, the view doesn't render as I want it (the divs containing the images don't line up properly):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="detail">
    <div class="detail_image_container">
        <div class="main_image_container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300" class="main_image" />
        </div>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50" class="thumbnail selected"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50" class="thumbnail "/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50" class="thumbnail "/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50" class="thumbnail "/></li>
        <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50" class="thumbnail "/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="detail_info_panel">
    <div>SOME TEXT HERE</div>
    <div>SOME TEXT HERE</div>
    <div>SOME TEXT HERE</div>
    <div>SOME TEXT HERE</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.detail>div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.detail_image_container>* {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li img {
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

li img.selected {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Here is how it looks [with](http://jsfiddle.net/emwtU/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/emwtU/1/) the `img {vertical-align:middle;}`.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Define your***

```
.detail_image_container>* {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/emwtU/3/)**

Comment: This does seem to fix my problem, but could you add an explanation as to why?

Comment: yes you define display:inline-block; but not define vertical-align; so that if you define your HTML Element display : inline-block; than please define vertical-align: top,middle, bottom any one according to your requirements ...